# Building Spark with mvn fails

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to build spark 1.5.0. I am using this command:

```
sh ./make-distribution.sh --name 2.6.0 --tgz  -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive
```

But get the following error code:

```
Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-launcher_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed. CompileFailed.
```

Also I get this error message:

```
Required file not found: scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar
```

Does anybody know, how I can fix this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the content of `make-distribution.sh`? How does your `pom.xml` look like? Can you please supply the relevant parts of the build output in context with these messages rather than just single lines.

Comment: Do you have scala 2.10 installed?

Answer (score 9):

Shutdown zinc first. See the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#speeding-up-compilation-with-zinc)

```
./build/zinc-<version>/bin/zinc -shutdown
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver! :-)